# Angular's unit testing for server sent events with just Karma-Jasmine

Tags: angular, typescript, unit-testing, jasmine, karma-jasmine

I am using Angular for frontend and Python for backend. I am using server sent events (SSE) to stream data from server to UI. Everything is working fine, but I am unable to write unit tests for the same in angular.

**abc.component.ts**

```js
streamMessages() {
  this.isPaused = false;
  this.messages = [];

  const url = this.urlConfig.stream;

  var eventSource = new EventSource(url);

  eventSource.addEventListener('message', (e) => {
    this.messages.push(e.data);
  });

  eventSource.addEventListener('error', (e) => {
    eventSource.close();

    console.log('ERROR!');

    this.isPaused = true;
  });

  eventSource.addEventListener('close', () => {
    eventSource.close();

    console.log('CLOSED!');
  });
}
```

**abc.component.spec.ts**

```js
describe('#streamMessages', () => {
  let mockEventSource: jasmine.SpyObj<EventSource>;

  beforeEach(() => {
    mockEventSource = jasmine.createSpyObj('EventSource', ['addEventListener']);
  });

  it('should push new message when new message is received', () => {

    mockEventSource.addEventListener.and.callFake((type: string, event: any) => {
      console.log(type, event)
    });

    component.streamMessages();

    expect(component.messages.length).toBeGreaterThan(0);
  });
});
```

I need to write unit tests for all the three scenarios.

Any leads would be a great help. Thanks in advance!

---

P.S: I don't want to use test bed. I need to accomplish this just with the help of Karma-Jasmine.

Comment: globalThis.EventSource = function() {return mockEventSource}

Comment: Do you have any reference on this? I am not aware how to use this. Can't we do this by creating jasmine mocks?

Comment: I've added this line so you would see where is the gap in your understanding. It is not a clean solution for sure. In your component `globalThis.EventSource`(same as `EventSource`) is used as a constructor, so the only way to make the component use the mock without changing the component's code is to replace the global constructor with the mock one, as I've done in the line above

Comment: I think, first I need to mock `var eventSource = new EventSource(url);` because I am getting `404` error for the URL. But, I am not getting how to do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to find a solution for this.

I changed this line:

```js
var eventSource = new EventSource(url);
```

to this:

```js
this.eventSource = new EventSource(url);
```

and used the `eventSourc`'s `dispatchEvent` method to emit the events like this:

```js
component.eventSource.dispatchEvent(new Event('error'));
```

Similarly, I did the same for other 2 events, and the it was unit tested as well as the lines were covered too.